# How do I pass data to the key and link of a link element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, html-framework-7

I'm making an app using VueJS and Framework7, and I'm having trouble understanding how to apply dynamic route matching to my app.

My app has two pages, main view and info page. On the main page, there is a list of links that all lead to the info page. However, the links are generated from API data, and I wish to do the same on the info page. What I'm trying to do is pass the `id` parameter from the API data into the link address, so that it's stored in there even while I load the same info page template. Using that `id`, I'd like to identify which data to print on the info page from the API data.

Here is my link element:

```
<f7-list-item v-for="lowerBoss in lowerBosses" :key="lowerBoss.id" :data="lowerBoss" class="single-boss subheading white" link="/boss/lowerBoss.id" onclick="console.log(lowerBoss)">
 {{ lowerBoss.name }} 
</f7-list-item>
```

So here I am trying to pass the `id` from the `lowerBoss` object into the link address and key. I tried to `console.log` the object as well, but whenever I click on this link, I get an error saying `lowerBoss is not defined`.

I am aware that I should most likely be using `router-link` for this, but I had trouble getting that to work - the links would not work wherever they led. Besides that, I had the same issue with them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above is right. You have to remmeber, that every property that written as usual `<component link="some-link/object.id"></component>` will not be parsed, but will be passed as **string**. So you have to use `:link="'/bla/bla/'+object.id"`.

lowerBoss will be available inside f7 component as "data", because of  **`:data="lowerBoss"`** this part of your tag.

Check this [Vue.js Passing Static or Dynamic Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props)

To handle events you have to use vue.js directives [Event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events)

Comment: Thank you, but as I already replied to the above answer, it still doesn't seem to pass the property - I cannot even `console.log(lowerBoss)` inside the `f7-list-item` tag.

Comment: It is because you trying to handle native "onclick" event, and it is not going to work like that

Comment: Okay, I didn't realise that, thank you! How would I pass this `id` forward to the info page? I tried `console.log(this.$route.params.id)` but it only returns `undefined`. I'm not sure I'm doing this right at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
  <f7-list-item v-for="lowerBoss in lowerBosses" :key="lowerBoss.id" :data="lowerBoss" class="single-boss subheading white" :link="'/boss/'+lowerBoss.id">
     {{ lowerBoss.name }} 
    </f7-list-item>
```

Comment: Still gives me the same error, unfortunately. It seems I cannot access `lowerBoss` (or `lowerBosses`) anywhere within the `f7-list-item` component, besides inside `v-for`. I'm really confused.

Comment: You should define export default {
   
  props :{
      id:String
    },
   data(props) {
return {
}
}